# Null Response from Microsoft Emotion Apis

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services

I am always getting response string "[]" in return when using Microsoft Cognitive services Emotion APIs, whenever i send the image obtaining through front-camera in android.

When i checked it with the sample image it gives the required result(Emotion analysis).

I don't know what's the problem with front camera image.

```
public void AnalyzeImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    AsyncTask<InputStream, String, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<InputStream, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(InputStream... params) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
            Map<String, Object> mapParams = new HashMap<>();
            String path = serviceHost + "/recognize";

            String uri = getUrl(path, mapParams);

            mapParams.clear();

            byte[] data = output.toByteArray();

            mapParams.put("data", data);
            String json="";
            try {
                 json = (String) webInvoke("POST", uri, mapParams, "application/octet-stream", false);
                Log.d("RESPONSE", json);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tvImageEmotion.setText(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}

public static String getUrl(String path, Map<String, Object> params) {
    StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer(path);

    boolean start = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (start) {
            url.append("?");
            start = false;
        } else {
            url.append("&");
        }

        try {
            url.append(param.getKey() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue().toString(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return url.toString();
}    


private Object webInvoke(String method, String url, Map<String, Object> data, String contentType, boolean responseInputStream) throws Exception, Exception {
    HttpPost request = null;

    request = new HttpPost(url);

    boolean isStream = false;

    if (contentType != null && !contentType.isEmpty()) {
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("octet-stream")) {
            isStream = true;
        }
    } else {
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    request.setHeader(headerKey, "0e843fb762464d82ae6f486bad99f629");

    try {
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity((byte[]) data.get("data")));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            if (!responseInputStream) {
                return readInput(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } else {
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error executing POST request! Received error code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to the problem, actually the image clicked through Camera is rotated to 90 degree, that's why Emotion API was unable to detect any face in the image.When I corrected the image rotation it works perfectly.